# WPF Child Window - Remote Desktop Session

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, remote-desktop

We have a WPF application that has a main window, and 1 child window shown by ShowDialog with ShowInTaskBar set to false.

We save their positions on close, and set Window.Left and Top when re-opened.

Problem is, when you remote desktop into a computer with multiple monitors and then open the child window with a saved position offscreen, there is no way to bring it onto the single monitor.

Is there a something we can change on the child window to make windows handle this issue?  The main window doesn't have this issue (I thought it might be related to ShowInTaskBar or the fact it is the main window).

Is there a better way for us to store the window location?

Comment: Found a link here: http://wpf.nickthuesen.com/?p=27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default way within WPF to access any available screen other then the primary screen.

WPF does have [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight.aspx) and [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth.aspx) to work with the primary screen however to get information on screens excpluding the primary you would have to make use of the [System.Windows.Forms.Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class.

If you went the System.Windows.Forms.Screen class route you could save relevant data about the window based on the screen at which it resides. Then upon reading the values in you can force the window to the desired screen based on the number of screens residing in the [System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) array. It gives you flexibility for placement as you can take advantage of all available screen within the system versus just the primary.

**EDIT:**

If you are not concerned with getting the screen information in a modular manner (information per screen versus the aggregate of all available screens) and do not want to make use of the System.Windows.Forms.Screen class you can make use of the [SystemParameters.VirtualScreen*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603177.aspx) properties which will provide the aggregate of available screens.

Comment: I think SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight and VirtualScreenWidth are what I need.  I am about to test this out.  Good to know there is nothing built in to "magically" fix this issue, though.

Comment: @Jonathan VirtualScreenHeight/VirtualScreenWidth should be the total size of all available screens versus an isolated view of each screen via the array; the caveat with this approach is the assumption that both monitors are displaying the same resolution and both are say 16:9 or 4:3

Comment: The only way someone could cause a problem would be to position the window on a secondary monitor, close my app, then change the resolution on that monitor.  For simplicity, I would rather not reference WinForms and suffer the .01% chance someone could cause this issue.  There are better uses for my time.

Comment: VirtualScreenHeight/VirtualScreenWidth works great from our testing today.  I'm marking you as the answer, since you did explain that Windows/WPF doesn't automatically adjust anything when remoting into a PC.

Comment: @Jonathan Glad to hear it worked; I will also edit my answer to include the notes about VirtualScreenHeight/Width

Answer (score -1):

It should always be possible to get any window back on screen. The following steps hook the currently active window to the mouse cursor:

- Press Alt+Space to open the system menu
- Press M for 'Move'
- Press the right arrow key
- now move the mouse

Comment: How would you achieve this with ShowInTaskbar set to false?  There is no item in the Alt+Tab menu or taskbar.  Besides, how could I expect any "civilian" user to know how to do this?

Comment: Alt+Space brings up the system menu for the active window -- ShowInTaskbar has nothing to do with it. But yes, this would only be helpful for those who know how to do it.

Comment: @Jonathan As Joe already said this has nothing to do with ShowInTaskbar. When the user opens the child window it becomes the active window, even if it is off-screen. Then you can do above steps to get it back on screen.

Comment: And you expect the average user to be able to follow the above steps?

Comment: @Jonathan An average user yes. But I fully agree that you should solve this programmatically. Its just that you said 'there is no way to bring it onto the single monitor', and I felt compelled to enlighten you :).

Comment: Impossible.  No way an average user would be able to operate the "Move" menu via Alt+Space, then M, then the arrow keys.  Especially if the window is offscreen.  I would say the right-click context menu would help in this situation, but the combination of ShowDialog and ShowInTaskbar do no allow the context menu on the item in the task bar.